# Check if a value is into an array

Tags: arrays, forms, coldfusion, struct

I've a form with this radio button:

```
<ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="1" /> Sunday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="2" /> Monday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="3" /> Tuesday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="4" /> Wednesday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="5" /> Thursday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="6" /> Friday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="repeat_period_week_day" value="7" /> Saturday</li>
</ul>
```

On form submission, I would like check which of these radios were ticked by user. Is it possible to verify without looping? I mean is there in CFML a function similar to the `in_array()` found PHP or something close ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the values of all the checkboxes that were checked will be submitted as a comma-delimited list.  So if Sunday and Saturday were checked and the form submitted, you'd end up with:

```
form.repeat_period_week_day= "1,7"
```

If you wanted to find out if the Saturday box was checked, you could use the [ListFind()](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/#ListFind) function like so:

```
ListFind(form.repeat_period_week_day,7)
```

Comment: A truly simple and accurate example. You should provide some code for him.

Comment: As a side note. This is the behaviour of all URL or FORM parameters that are repeated one than once. They get concatenated into a list of the values.